# Google Smartlock is not showing Facebook profile picture when the credentials are requested

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I have recently integrated google smartlock with my app. Currently, I am trying to save FB credentials with the following code.

```
    Credential.Builder builder =new Credential.Builder(user.getEmail()) //FB Email
            .setAccountType(accountType) //IdentityProviders.FACEBOOK
            .setProfilePictureUri(uri); // Facebook graph image url 
                                        // with host graph.facebook.com
```

When I request the credential from the smartlock , I am not able to see user image associated with user FB profile account on the dialog that appears asking user to select the account to login in the App. One thing I have observed that if I use static url like below then it is working fine .
https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg
But If I use dynamic url like the one below which needs url redirection then it is not working.
https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXX/picture?height=200&width=200&return_ssl_resources=true

Does anyone facing the same issue ?

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Play Services not handling the redirect correctly, it's on the backlog to get fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync