# App and website saved password is not sync

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

Google Smart Lock feature implemented in my Android App.
I am trying to sync password b/w my website and my Android App.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites) document, I have done all required changes.

My website is [here](https://auth-test.centurylink.com).

Digital asset link file is uploaded on [this server](https://auth-test.centurylink.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json).

**In Manifest I have added below code.**
`<meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />`

**in String.xml**
`<string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">[{\"include\": \"https://auth-test.centurylink.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json\"</string>`

App has been published to play-store in Beta, before 2 weeks.
Also Submitted [**Website / app credential linking**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc3FCn8ccGpgXd1jtLBVRlNJ6EhWQK50hNO5jT_9nuqHI79pg/viewform) form multiple time,

Still have not received any mail of confirmation nor if there are any mistakes.

What is the best way to resolve or communicate with the team?
How much time it takes to sync password b/w Web and App?

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Please answer as I am also facing a similar problem.

Comment: @Omer no its not resolved. Still looking for a solution

Comment: @Omer It is not resolved, did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the same situation, I will publish and confirm as this answer.

> You need to publish your app to the public channel, unfortunately publishing it to beta isn't enough for the linking to be picked up. Once that's done, the link will be picked up automatically within two business days.

[Website App smart lock password association not confirmed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57052513/website-app-smart-lock-password-association-not-confirmed-yet)

Comment: I have published app. with containing above metadata.
Link:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.centurylink.ctl_droid_wrap

Comment: Once published, it became valid.

Comment: can you able to send me your App Link?
and have you implemented smart lock in Website also?

Comment: This app cannot be accessed from abroad. sorry.
As I learned later, it wasn't because it was published, but because the credential api client was different from other apps.
When I tried to use the same client, it was displayed even if it was not published.

Comment: ok, one question is you have implemented smart lock feature in Website and Android app right?

Comment: Android only.The official website has been updated.https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites